# knockout js, find all the parent nodes id from a item selected in tree view

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

We are creating a tree view with n(any) levels.

I have taken [this tree solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/Al3Tx6?p=preview), but now I am stuck with an issue.

We wanted to get all the parent nodes `id` from the selected node.

Can anyone please help us solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you can get the id of the current selected node, which is already a concatenation of the parents ids.

Replace

```
  <div data-bind="with: selected">
    Selected Node:                 <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </div>
```

With

```
  <div data-bind="with: selected">
    Selected Node:                 <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    Ids: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
  </div>
```

If you want an array with all parent ids, you can do the following:

1. Add a parent property to each treenode (`parent`) and fill it in the constructor
2. Add an array of parent ids (`parentIds`)
3. Create a function that will go through all the TreeNodes and fill the `parentIds` array

Check this code (1. & 2.):

```
function TreeNode(values) {
      var self = this;
      ko.mapping.fromJS(values, { children: { create: createNode }}, this);
      this.expanded = ko.observable(false);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.children().length; i++)
          this.children()[i].parent = this;
      this.parentIds = [];
      this.collapsed = ko.computed(function() {
      return !self.expanded();
    })
  }
```

And this (3.):

```
function setParents(rootNode) {
    if (ko.isObservable(rootNode.children) && rootNode.children().length)
      for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.children().length; i++) {
        if (rootNode.children()[i].parent)
          rootNode.children()[i].parentIds = rootNode.children()[i].parent.parentIds.slice(0);
        rootNode.children()[i].parentIds.push(rootNode.children()[i].parent.id())
        setParents(rootNode.children()[i]);
      }
  }

  setParents(root);
```

You can check **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K0mrUOuRlqYKLapHqgXS?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i wanted all the parent nodes id.

in this case if i click on the node with id "1.1.2" >> i wanted a result like

1 >> 1.1 >> 1.1.2

Comment: is there a way to traverse in reverse order and get all the parent id's of the selected item?